# How Xubuntu decides which windows to group together in the taskbar?

Tags: xubuntu, window, taskbar

Currently, Xubuntu is grouping together Mathematica, IPython Qt Console and Spotify, which makes no sense. Is there a way to modify this behavior? How Xubuntu decides which windows go together in the taskbar?

Comment: Windows are grouped by WM_CLASS one would say. Not sure how that explains Spotify to be grouped with IPython and Mathematica (from the terminal). Could you check the different `WM_CLASS` outputs when you open a terminal, type `xprop WM_CLASS`, and then click on the window (for each of the applications)?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I get: `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "spotify", "Spotify"` for Spotify and `WM_CLASS(STRING) = "XMathematica"` for Mathematica.

Comment: By *grouping*, you mean put *in order*, or grouped under one button? The first is an option that can be changed, the latter should be by `WM_CLASS`, if not something is wrong :).

Comment: @JacobVlijm I mean grouped under one button.

Comment: ??? That makes no sense indeed, and seems not to be correct. On my system (VM) all is grouped by WM_CLASS.

Comment: Do you have Mathematica, Spotify, or IPython Qt Console? Those three are grouped together here.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Or is there a setting somewhere that affects this?

Comment: I installed `IPython Qt Console`,  Mathematica seems to be proprietary software.  There is a setting, but the word *grouping* is used in the sense of *sorting*.  If you right-click on the panel > panel preferences > items (tab) > double click on the "Window Buttons" item in the list, you'll get there. Without exception, windows are grouped by `WM_CLASS` on my system.

Comment: @JacobVlijm To test, you will need at least two of the programs I mentioned. Spotify has a free version.

Comment: @JacobVlijm I have that setting set to `None - allow drag & drop`